# Is the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Schauder basis of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis, schauder-basis

Let $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the standard basis of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: b_n = \frac{1}{n}e_n$

My question is if $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Thanks.

Comment: If $a=(a_1,a_2,...)\in\ell^2$ when $a=\sum_n(na_n)b_n$, and if $0=\sum_na_nb_n$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: thanks for your answer @elmer

Comment: Just help the next person, if you can.

Comment: wow very nice comment!!!! I'll try it